# Как правильно описать AsyncTask c входящим String и исходящим ArrayList

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Я пытаюсь вынести `AsyncTask` во внешний класс. Входящим параметром должен быть `String`, а вернуться `ArrayList`. Не получается. Даже не попадаю в GetSiteData при отладке.
Буду признателен за любые советы.
Заранее спасибо.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public int dayOfTheWeekOnTheSite;
    public ArrayList<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> dayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // public ArrayList<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // public ArrayList<String> dayEventList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<List<String>> dayEventLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>(7);
    public ArrayList<TextView> tvRC = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    public RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    public int ORIENTATION;
    public int mWith;
    public int mHeigh;
    public String myURL;
    private Calendar dateList;
//  private Calendar timeList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         myURL = "http://www.sportlife.ua/ru/services/schedule/14875";
        GetSiteData GSD = new GetSiteData();
         GSD.execute();
//      try {
//          GSD.get();
//      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
```

**GetSiteData.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GetSiteData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    public ArrayList<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // public ArrayList<String> dayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> dayEventList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<List<String>> dayEventLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>(7);
    // public ArrayList<TextView> tvRC = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    public String eventNames;
    // public String myURL;
    public String tmpString;
    public Elements time;
    public Elements currentday;
    public Elements date;
    private ProgressDialog prog;

    /**
     * Метод выполняющий запрос в фоне, в версиях выше 4 Андроида, запросы в
     * главном потоке выполнять нельзя, поэтому все что вам нужно выполнять -
     * выносите в отдельный поток
     * @return 
     */

    protected  ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String myURL = "http://www.sportlife.ua/ru/services/schedule/14875";
        // класс который захватывает страницу
        Document doc;

        try { // определяем откуда будем скачивать данные

            doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(myURL)
                    .timeout(6000)
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36")
                    .get(); // задаем с какого места парсить

            /**
             * Выбираем содержимое расписания по индексу столбца td:eq(Индекс)
             */

            /** Чистим списки */
            timeList.clear();
            // dayEventList.clear();
            // dateList.clear();

            /** Формируем линки и наполняем коллекции */
            // Время занятий
            String link = "#shedule-content tr:gt(0) td:eq(0)";
            time = doc.select(link);

            // // Дата
            // link = "#shedule-content thead span";
            // date = doc.select(link);

            /** Заносим в ArrayList время занятий */
            for (Element times : time) {
                if (times.className().equals("time-col")) {
                    timeList.add(times.text());
                }
            }

            // for (Element dates : date) {
            // dateList.add(dates.text()); // Записываем в ArrayList дату
            //
            // }

            /**
             * // События дня
             * 
             * // List<List<String>> dayEventList = new ArrayList<>(); //
             * dayEventList.add(new ArrayList<String>()); //
             * dayEventList.get(i).add(dayEventList);
             * 
             * /** НАПОЛНЕНИЕ МАССИВА СОБЫТИЙ ДНЯ
             * 
             * 
             * for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) { link = "#shedule-content tr:gt(0) "
             * + "td:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")"; currentday = doc.select(link);
             * 
             * fillDayEventLilsts(currentday);
             * 
             * ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
             * tmpList.addAll(dayEventList); dayEventLists.add(tmpList);
             * 
             * currentday.clear(); dayEventList.clear(); }
             */

        } catch (IOException e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return timeList;
    }

    /**
     * Метод для занесения в ArrayList событий дня, входящий параметр -
     * currentday
     * 
     */
    private ArrayList<String> fillDayEventLilsts(Elements currentday) {
        for (Element event : currentday) {
            if (event.hasText() == true) {
                Elements mEvents = Jsoup.parse(event.html()).select(
                        ".event-item-body");
                /** Может быть несколько занятий на одно и тоже время */
                int i = 0;
                tmpString = "";
                do {
                    Element textEvent = mEvents.get(i);
                    tmpString = textEvent.text();
                    if (eventNames == null) {
                        eventNames = tmpString;
                    } else {

                        eventNames = eventNames + tmpString + "\n";
                        // eventNames = eventNames.trim();
                    }
                    i++;
                } while (i < mEvents.size());

                /** События заносим в список */
                dayEventList.add(eventNames.trim());
                eventNames = "";
            } else
                dayEventList.add("");

        }
        return dayEventList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // prog.setMessage("З'єднання...");
        // prog.show();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> timeList) {
        super.onPostExecute(timeList);

        // mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // prog.dismiss();
    }

}
```